# Convergence problems created by jittered coordinates

Tags: r, autocorrelation, spatial, convergence, mixed-model

I am creating a mixed model and including a spatial correlation. My data points include lat long values although some are duplicated. I have two questions about dealing with these.

1. To specify the spatial correlation there must not be any distances of 0. Therefor, I jittered my coordinates to ensure that there were no duplicates. The maximum that they are jittered is 0.01 degrees lat/long. As this is data on a global scale, while these small numbers make the computation more difficult? Have any effect at all? Most of my data has 2 or 3 decimals, while the jittered has more (not fully represented in the example)
2. When I jitter the same data multiple times it make the difference if a model will or will not converge. For example, for the same dataset, with the coordinates jittered 2 times, one may converge while one does not? Is there another way to solve this problem? (not jittering/not averaging at the location) My current workaround has been to write the jittered coordinates to file, and use the same ones – but this doesn’t seem to be the best solution.

I have created example data to show my problem. If you run the code once, and then rerun the code below the stars again (or maybe three times) there may be a convergence error. I ran this 3 times, and found that all things staying the same (except the jittered coordinates) there was 1 time where the data did not converge.

```
#Simulate data
lat = runif(1500, -90, 90)
long = runif(1500, -90,90)
y = log(runif(1500, 10, 2500))
x1 = log(runif(1500, 0, 5))
x2 = log(runif(1500, 90, 2000))
x3 = log(runif(1500, 1, 1000))
LC = sample(c(1,2,3), 1500, replace = TRUE)
# to simulate duplicates
i = 0
while(i<50){
  a = sample(c(1:1500),1)
  b = sample(c(1:1500),1)
  lat[a]=lat[b]
  long[a]=long[b]
  if (i <9){
    c = sample(c(1:1500),1)
    d = sample(c(1:1500),1)
    lat[a]=lat[c] = lat[d] =lat[b]
    long[a]=long[c] = long[d]=long[b] }
  i = i +1  }
# *************** repeat paste below to re-jitter and test for new convergence errors*****
coordmat = matrix(c(lat,long), ncol = 2)
newcoords = jitterDupCoords(coordmat, max = 0.01)
lat = newcoords[,1]
long = newcoords[,2]

dframe = data.frame(y = y, x1 = x1, x2=x2, x3=x3, lat =lat, long = long, LC = LC )
fit2 <- lme(y ~ x1+x2+x3,random = ~(x1+x2)|LC, cor = corGaus(form =~lat+ long), data = dframe)
```

Please let me know if there is anything I need to clarify.
Thanks for your help!